# Python - Downloading images using Wget. How to add a string to each file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wget

I'm using the following Python code to download images from a certain website. It's part of a code that I'm using to make a web scraper.

```
for url in links:

    # Invoke wget download method to download specified url image.
    local_image_filename = wget.download(url)

    # Print out local image file name.
    local_image_filename

    continue
```

It's working well, but I want to know if it's possible to add a string as a prefix to each file...
My ideia is get the page title via Xpath and add as a prefix for each file.
I don't know where to add a string in this code. Can someone help me?

For example, I'm downloading these files:
logo.jpg, plans.jpg, circle.jpg

And I need to add a prefix, like these:
Beautiful_Plan_logo.jpg, Beautiful_Plan_plans.jpg, Beautiful_Plan_circle.jpg

Following I'll put the entire code:

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import wget

##################################################
# getting url images #
##################################################

url = "https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/house-plans/blackberry-blossom/"

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.add_headers = [{'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla'}]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

raw = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')

imgs = soup.find_all('img')

links = []

for img in imgs:
    link = img.get('src')
    links.append(link)
    print(links)


################################################
# downloading images #
################################################

for url in links:

    # Invoke wget download method to download specified url image.
    local_image_filename = wget.download(url)

    # Print out local image file name.
    local_image_filename

    continue
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

python module `wget` has an option `out`, which determines the name of the output file. For example, the following script downloads 3 images, adding a prefix `Beautiful_Plan_`.

```
import wget
base_url = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/'
image_names = ['airplane.png', 'arctichare.png', 'baboon.png']
prefix = 'Beautiful_Plan_'
for image_name in image_names:
  wget.download(base_url + image_name, out = prefix + image_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use shutil for this

```
import shutil
prefix = "prefix_"
#your piece of code
for url in links:

    # Invoke wget download method to download specified url image.
    local_image_filename = wget.download(url)

    # Print out local image file name.
    local_image_filename
    shutil.copy(local_image_filename, prefix+local_image_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ruchirkhatri

Answer (score 1):

use os.rename as per [this documentation](https://datatofish.com/rename-file-python/)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote code for making a seperate file with the extra information up front with a seperator.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import wget

##################################################
# getting url images #
##################################################

url = "https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/house-plans/blackberry-blossom/"

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.add_headers = [{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

raw = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')

imgs = soup.find_all('img')

links = []

for img in imgs:
    link = img.get('src')
    links.append(link)
    # print(links)

################################################
# downloading images #
################################################

for url in links:
    # Invoke wget download method to download specified url image.
    try:
        local_image_filename = wget.download(url)
    except ValueError:
        break

    # Print out local image file name.
    print(local_image_filename)

    with open(local_image_filename, 'r') as myFile:
        try:
            data = myFile.read()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            data = "UNICODE DECODE ERROR"
        except ValueError:
            data = "VALUE ERROR"
        print(data)
        print(type(data))
        myFile.close()

    newSaveString = str(local_image_filename) + "SeperatorOfSomeKind" + str(data)
    newFileName = "NEW_" + local_image_filename

    with open(newFileName, 'w') as myFile:
        myFile.write(newSaveString)
        myFile.close()

    continue
```